# NoMethodError in StaticPages#manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm rails noob. I have a problem with contact form.
I have an error: `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`

```
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @contact_forms.name %>
</p>
```

My manager.html.erb is:

```
<div>
    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= @contact_forms.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Text:</strong>
      <%= @contact_forms.text %>
    </p>
</div>
```

My contact_form_controller.rb is:

```
class ContactFormController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    @contact_forms = Contact_form.new(params[:contact_form])

  @contact_forms.save

      redirect_to root_path
      end

      def show
        @contact_forms = Contact_form.all
      end
  end
```

My file with migrates:

```
class CreateContactForms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contact_forms do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :phone
      t.string :email
      t.text :text

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

my static_pages_controller.rb is

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def manager
  end
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your `static_pages` controller in the question

Comment: I did it. Actions are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

You didn't defined `@contact_forms` in the `manager` method of `static_pages` controller, so is the error. Defining it like below should solve your problem.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def manager
    @contact_forms = ContactForm.all
  end
end
```

***Update:***

You should also iterate over `@contact_forms` like below in the `manager.html.erb`

```
<div>
  <% @contact_forms.each do |contact_form| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= contact_form.name %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Text:</strong>
      <%= contact_form.text %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this problem is solved, but occure problem with "text" method:
undefined method `text' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: Yes :) But I have next problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838608/contact-form-doesnt-work-it-does-not-save-to-db

Answer (score 1):

> I'm rails noob

Welcome to the family! [You're a newb, not noob](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Noobs%20vs.%20Newbs) :)

Pavan's answer is right; since you're new I wanted to give you some context:

---

> undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass

This error means you're trying to call a *method* on a variable which has not been defined / populated.

In your case, **`@contact_forms` is not defined**.

The confusing part for many new Ruby developers is that instead of halting the entire program, Ruby populates the `NilClass` & claims there to be an error with it

So whilst you'd expect it to say the variable was undeclared, it gives you a message about how a method doesn't work.

--

To resolve your issue, you need to use the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :contact_forms
resources :static_pages

#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def manager
      @contact_forms = ContactForm.all
   end
end
```

To steal from Pavan, this has to be backed up by looping through the `@contact_forms` variable (unless you've populated it with a single instance of the `ContactForm` model):

```
#app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb
<% @contact_forms.each do |form| %>
    <%= form.name %>
<% end %>
```

---

As an aside, I would *never* recommend calling a controller `StaticPages`.

When you get more into Ruby, you'll find out about the *object orientated* nature of the language:

[image]

I explain this a lot; basically, it means you have to keep your program centered around *objects*, in the case of Rails, are populated by the `Models`.

As such, you need to think about what data object you're trying to manipulate when showing this view. At present, it seems you want to show a `contact` form -- I'd put it in its own method in the `ApplicationController`:

```
#config/routes.rb
match "contact", to: "application#contact_form", via: [:get, :post]

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def contact_form
     if request.post? 
         #post contact form
     else
         #load contact form
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: hi! ) Sorry, I've seen your comment only now. One more time thank you a lot! :) You answers helps me too much.